# angular 4: aframe orbit-controls does not work

Tags: angular, controls, aframe, orbit

i try to implement this https://github.com/tizzle/aframe-orbit-controls-component into my app. 
added

```
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/tizzle/aframe-orbit-controls-component/v0.1.13/dist/aframe-orbit-controls-component.min.js"></script>
```

into index.html
where as the a-frame component is working, the orbit-controls seems not to run.

when adding following code to app.component.html:

```
<a-scene>

  <a-entity
      id="camera"
      camera="fov: 80; zoom: 1;"
      position="0 2 5"
      orbit-controls="
          autoRotate: false;
          target: #target;
          enableDamping: true;
          dampingFactor: 0.125;
          rotateSpeed:0.25;
          minDistance:3;
          maxDistance:100;
          "
      mouse-cursor="">
      <a-entity geometry="primitive:cone; radius-bottom:1; radius-top:0" scale=".33 1 .33" position="0 0 0" rotation="90 0 0" material="color: #0099ff; transparent: true; opacity:0.5"></a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <a-entity id="target">
      <a-box id="box" position="-1 0.5 1" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
      <a-sphere id="sphere" position="0 1.25 -1" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
      <a-cylinder id="cylinder" position="1 0.75 1" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
      <a-plane position="0 0 0" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
  </a-entity>

  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>

</a-scene>
```

there is no camera orbiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be updated for 0.7.0. You can either use 0.6.0 or use this PR to get it working with A-Frame 0.7.0: https://github.com/tizzle/aframe-orbit-controls-component/pull/29